# Adding custom functions PHP to use in a views template

Tags: 7, views, theming

I want to use a custom function in `views-view-fields--field-name.tpl.php` template file. Where do I have to put it? Is it possible to use it in template.php in some preprocess functions?

Comment: Add your function in any file and include the file in views-view-field--field_name.tpl.php.

Comment: You should include the file in **views-view-field--field_name.tpl.php** using **module_load_include**. Example :  module_load_include('file_type', 'module_name', 'base_file_name'); https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7

Answer (score 4):

You can use a preprocess function in your `template.php` file. For example:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view_fields__field_name(&$vars) {
  // Do your changes for the field here
}
```

Comment: call to undefined function it says...

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7, you can achieve this using [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) OR [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php).

- Create a .inc file in the custom module, which will keep all the template files functions, or if you have only one function then just add the function in your custom module.
- Go to your template file (views-view-fields--field-name.tpl.php) and include the file using `module_load_include()` or `include_once()`

  - If it is a .inc file, use `module_load_include('file_type', 'module_name', 'base_file_name');`
  - If it is a function in a custom module, use `include_once 'FILE_PATH';`

Comment: If it is a function in a module, then there isn't any need of using `include_once()` since every enabled module is loaded when Drupal completes its bootstrap. It's only on early bootstrap phases that the enabled modules are still to be loaded.